# Finding Apache files

Tags: apache2, files, find

I'm using a newly installed Ubuntu 18:04 and am new to Unix systems, but very experienced in Windows
I've carefully followed an instruction set to install the LAMP files and Apache has been running successfully.
However I have not been able to find any files associated with Apache and in particular its .conf file
Also the instructions I used indicated to use the "sudo chmod" command to ensure I have the right permissions for folders /usr/var/www/  This folder did not exist, so I created it, but the chmod command continues to say the folder doesn't exist.
How do I find these files? And why doesn't chmod see the folder I created?

The instructions I used were at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04  None of the files or folders mentioned appeared on my computer.  I've just done a search for etc with nothing found.  Before posting the original question I'd searched for both Apache2 and apache2 with nothing found then or again now when I've repeated the search.  The search method I used was the Search Command in the Files app, also looking in each of thee folders with that app.  Also the chmod command does not see the files.  Lastly the Ubuntu was professionally installed completely replacing Windows 10 on the computer if that may be relevant.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show that you used the guide at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04 please. Next you say that even though you followed this guide you could not find the configuration files. Please show the exact command(s) you used to try to find the files. We can't help you without knowing what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Configuration files for apache are found under `/etc/apache2`.

The default document root for apache is `/var/www/html` (not the `/usr/var/www` that you stated) and that should be created by installing the apache packages.

Please edit your question to link to the instructions that you used - it sounds like there will be follow-up questions.